# React - How to share Child component states with Parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

**Background**

So I have a simple example, a Form component (Parent) and multiple Input components (Children). Each individual Input component will have an `useState` hook to initialize and manage its value's state.

**Issue**

As with most forms, I would like to submit all of the data to a backend for processing. However, the issue is that I cannot retrieve the state of value from each Child Input component.

```
// app.jsx
import Form from "./Form";

export default function App() {
  return <Form />;
}

// Form.jsx
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Wait, how do I retreive values from Children Inputs?");
};

const Form = () => {
  console.log("Form render");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      Sample Form
      <Input initial="username" name="user" />
      <Input initial="email" name="email" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;



// Input.jsx

import React from "react";
import useInputValue from "./useInputValue";

const Input = ({ name, initial }) => {
  const inputState = useInputValue(initial);

  console.log(`${name}'s value: ${inputState.value}`);
  return <input {...inputState} />;
};

export default Input;
```

**Plausible Solution**

Of course, I can lift the Input states up to the Form component, perhaps in an obj name values. However, if I do that, every time I change the Inputs, the Form will re-render, along with *all* of the Inputs.

To me, that is an undesirable side-effect. As my Form component gets bigger, this will be more costly to re-render all inputs (inside the form) every time one input changes.

Because of that, I would like to stick with my decision of having each individual input manage its own state, that way if one input changes, not all other input will re-render along with the Parent component.

**Question**

If each of the Child components manages its own state, could the Parent component access the value of that state and do actions (like form submission)?

**Update**

Many answers and comments mentioned that this is premature optimization and the root of all known evil; which I agree with, but to clarify, I am asking this question with a simple example because I wanted to find a viable solution to my current and more complex project. My web app has a huge form (where all states are lifted to the form level), which is getting re-rendered at every change in its inputs. Which seemed unnecessary, since only one input is changed at a time.

**Update #2**
Here is a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-water-lzey3g?file=/src/App.js) of the issue I am having. There are two forms, one with all states managed by individual Child input components, and the other has all states lifted up in the form level. Try entering some values and check the console for log messages. One can see that with all states lifted to the form level, every change will cause both inputs to be re-rendered.

Comment: Answer: No, u must lift the state up (see "data flows down" at docs). The main problem is that you doing premature optimizations, whats so "costly" in rerendering all inputs? Did you measure it? Is it a real bottleneck? You also can memoize every input if its still bothering u.

Comment: There could be multiple ways. But if you want each Input to have its own state, I'd suggest you use Context API [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to store, set and access form data. You can set data in each Input component, and access it in form (or any other component). There will be no re-rendering of the entire form when one of Input's change.

Comment: @DennisVash I am actually using this as a simple example, my web application involves a much bigger form, and my states are indeed lifted in the parent's level. I am seeing the parent's component re-render every time there is a change in the input states, and the overall UX when typing in forms does feel slower and choppier, and that is why I started to look for other viable solutions.

Comment: Have a look at react-hook-forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the thing you want is getting final values from input, assign ref to each input and access using emailRef.current.value in the submit function.

```
import { useState, useRef, forwardRef } from 'React';


    const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
      return <input ref={ref} value={value} onChange={(e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}} {...props} />;
    });
    
    const App = () => {
      const emailRef = useRef(null);
    
      const submit = () => {
        const emailString = emailRef.current.value
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <Input ref={emailRef} />
          <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Comment: This would have the Child manage its own states? Sorry, could you please clarify in an example?

Comment: I added the code, child component manages its own state. You can reach the value of input in the parent without rerender using ref.

Comment: wow that is amazing, I’ll have to read up more on forwarsRefs, and test a few things on codesandbox later tonight, I’ll be sure to vote for the answer right after

Answer (score 2):

I think yes, you can share state. Also there are 3 options:

1. I recommend you to use such library as Formik. It will help you in your case.
2. You can share state using useState() hook as props.
3. Use such tools as Redux Toolkit (if we are speaking about memoisation), useContext() and etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will have to check out Formik, but I was wondering if this can be done without any 3rd party tools/libraries. As for 2), please see updated info in question.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent needs to know about the childs state, you can

1. move the state up. This is resolved by passing down a setState function that the child calls (the states data is available in the parent)
2. use a context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
3. use a state management library e.g. redux

In your simple case I'd go with 1)

Comment: Hello Michael, I have mentioned in my question under Plausible Solutions on why I am not a fan of moving the State up. Once that is done, any changes in child will cause entire parent to re-render (since the changes in Child components changes the Parent state now). How would address that, and do you know if the latter two options will have that same issue?

Comment: This is premature optimization. But if you want to optimize and reduce re-renders you want to consider looking into useMemo / useCallback - a bit of re-renders will always happen, and I am quite optimistic that you are very far away from hitting performance implications based on your example

Comment: Even with useMemo/useCallback/memo to memoize functions, components and values; if the state is initialized at the parent's level, then any change in the state will cause re-render, or is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, when setState is called, the re-render is triggered. But that's desired behavior. Why wouldn't you want the UI to update if your data (state) changes?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated my question with some more context, it may have not been that clear on what I am trying to achieve.  I do want the UI to update, but only on the component that is being changed. If I lifted the states up to the Form, then every input change will cause the Form, and therefore all Inputs to re-render, which is not what I want. I only want the input that is being changed to be re-rendered, hope that makes sense